# Why can't I update my dates in database from 01/01/1753?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetimepicker, .net-2.0

when I update and insert dates into my database they always come out as 01/01/1753

[image]

code for updating

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@regdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datereg.MinDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@exdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = regexp.MinDate;
```

it used to be fine but now it just stays at 1753

Comment: Are you sure you are willing to put `MinDate` in the field? Checkout minimum dates in C#.

Comment: 1753 is the minimum date in SQL Server https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/53508789.html 

try to debug and inspect variable to check what value you are trying to set?

Comment: Do you really use MySQL, not MS SQL aka SQL Server?

Comment: @Akina yes, i do

Comment: If so then 1753 is a year created by your application code or the connector - MySQL have no any built-in reason to set this "magic" value. Enable general log temporarily and look for actual SQL code sent to MySQL server.